# Show that $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R} , f(x, y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$ is not differentiable at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was going to use the definition of derivative for $f : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ but when I was calculating $\nabla f(0, 0)$, it didn't exist, so now I'm stumped on what to do. Should I not plug in the point $(0, 0)$ into $\nabla f$ and then try to prove $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a) - \nabla f \cdot h}{||h||} \neq 0$$ 
for general $a$?

Comment: Not just doesn't equal 0, but does not exist.

Comment: There is a nice theorem stating that if $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, then all the directional derivatives of $f$ exists at $a$. The converse is not true though.

Answer (score 0):

If $\nabla f (x_0)$ does not exist then $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

When one wants to prove some function is *not* differentiable, it is usually not very efficient to work on the definition. All one needs in your particular case is to look at *some* direction that $f$ has not derivative at $(0,0)$.

Hint:

- Show that $f(x,x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.
- Show that the statement above implies that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I might start by considering the partial derivatives at (x,y) = 0. We have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\sqrt{\left|xy\right|}\right)$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\sqrt{\left|x\right|}\right)$ for $c=\sqrt{y}$, which is clearly not differentiable.